# How can I enable double tap actions on navigation buttons?

Tags: settings, android-12, navigation-bar, gestures

Before the latest Android update, I was so happy with my double tap functionalities. I had something like

- double triangle -> bring down the panel with notification,
- double circle -> lock screen
- double square -> I had it set to something I rarely used and so I don't remember, but it was settable
- hold triangle -> some thing swiping right on the first page of the home
- hold circle -> google assistant
- hold square -> split screen

All these things but the last 2 have disappeared with last update. I think before this update I was Android 11.

How can I enable those things again? I haven't found anything in the settings.

Comment: This looks like customization done by the manufacturer. Which device model are you using?

Comment: @AndrewT., OnePlus Nord CE 5G